# How to register Notes user with the Domino Web Administrator?

Tags: certificate-authority, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I set up a test IBM Domino 9.0.1 on Linux, configured the server with user with full admin rights, and was able to connect Note client application. When I tried to register a new user via the Web Administrator client, I got this message:

> No Certificate Authority ('CA') configured certifier available for
>   this domain.

The documentation says in order to register Notes users, one has to set up a server-based Certificate Authority(CA) and list both the Web administrator and its server as a registration authority(RA). How to set these up with Web Administrator client? Domino Server runs on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the web administrator only.

For most administration tasks you need a Domino administrator client. As Notes / Domino is all about security, and the main security is given using a 2- factor authentication you cannot set up basics without a client that uses that security feature. You need a Windows PC, the Domino Admin Client, the admin.id and the cert.id and all the passwords for these ids. Then you can setup the admin client and do the administration

The web administrator can be used for "basic" tasks later when everything else is set up.

It is NO replacement for an installed admin client...